# Automatic break when contents of a memory location changes or is read

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging

The old DEC Tru64 UNIX debugger had a feature (called "watchpoints to monitor variables") that would watch a memory location (or range of addresses) for read or write activity and when it detected such activity would break the program so you could investigate why.  See for details:

http://h30097.www3.hp.com/docs/base_doc/DOCUMENTATION/V50_HTML/ARH9QATE/DOCU_009.HTM

Is there any way to do this sort of thing in the VisualStudio debugger?  Or is there an add-on or some other tool that can do this under Windows?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yeah, you can do this in visual studio. You can create a "New Data Breakpoint" under the debug menu while you're broken in a running program. You then specify the address to watch and the number of bytes.

This only works for changing the value. I don't know how to watch for read access. However it's a very common question to want to know where a value got changed. I find that I don't want to know who reads a value as often.

Comment: The menu item is only enabled while the debugger is active. I thought for a while that it had been disabled in Express.

Answer (score 6):

Visual Studio [allows to set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/350dyxd0.aspx) breakpoints on memory location only 4 bytes length (on 32-bit Windows version). To catch memory access (read or write) you could use the following class:

```
struct protect_mem_t {
    protect_mem_t( void* addr, size_t size ) : addr(addr), size(size), is_protected(FALSE) { 
        protect(); 
    }
    ~protect_mem_t() { release(); }
    BOOL protect() { 
        if ( !is_protected ) {
            // To catch only read access you should change PAGE_NOACCESS to PAGE_READONLY
            is_protected = VirtualProtect( addr, size, PAGE_NOACCESS, &old_protect );
        }
        return is_protected;
    }
    BOOL release() { 
        if ( is_protected ) 
            is_protected = !VirtualProtect( addr, size, old_protect, &old_protect );
        return !is_protected;
    }

protected:
    void*   addr;
    size_t  size;
    BOOL    is_protected;
    DWORD   old_protect;
};
```

It changes access mode on selected memory pages. Page size is equal to 4096 bytes on 32-bit systems. Exception will be thrown on every access to protected memory. This class is limited in use to only large memory areas, but I hope it can be helpful.

It could be used in the following way:

```
// some_array should be aligned on PAGE_SIZE boundaries
protect_mem_t guard( &some_array, PAGE_SIZE );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use WINDBG and set a ba breakpoint on the desired address

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [the hwbreak project](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28071/Toggle-hardware-data-read-execute-breakpoints-prog). It even allows a data-breakpoint to be set when a location is read.

I modified it to only create one thread, and to reuse that thread for all data-breakpoints, but that was just for efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, data breakpoints can detect writes. Don't know if it's possible to check for read, though. I don't believe x86 has native support for that.