# How to set breakpoints programmatically in Visual C++?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, breakpoints

What I am trying to do is to monitor memory value changes at some specific addresses, like binding a callback func to the 'onChange' event.

One idea for now that I can think up is to use memory write breakpoint. So how to manipulate breakpoints programmatically in Visual C++?

Comment: You want set breakpoints at run-time? - Why you don't use conditional breakpoints?

Comment: @MM. I want to do this in my code, not in the debugger

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1261763/1762344 , http://stackoverflow.com/a/8008943/1762344

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft do provide a breakpoint interface which can be used for this purpose, have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/envdte.breakpoint.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte80.breakpoint2(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 6):

If you need to break into the debugger, use the [DebugBreak](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679297%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function, if necessary under a `#ifdef _DEBUG` `#endif` block

Comment: Also `_DEBUG` is irrelevent. The right thing is to use `IsDebuggerPresent`

Answer (score 1):

You can also place in your code:

__asm { int 3 }

If you are running under the VS debugger, that will invoke the breakpoint handler.

UPDATE:
Actually it is the same than using the MSVC instrinsic __debugbreak (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f408b4et.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I've had great success with [the hwbrk project](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28071/Toggle-hardware-data-read-execute-breakpoints-prog).

Comment: Great little project. Beware, that the BP is set per-thread, so you have to organize a loop to set it for each relevant thread when debugging a multithreaded app.